# How to add a global component (navigation) in Ionic React

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-react

I'm trying to add a global navigation/menu bar component in my Ionic React project, like you would do on any website.

So I've created a standard `<Nav/>` component i React, but it seems like I can only add it into specific pages in my Ionic app, not in my `App.tsx` file where the Router is set up.

My `App.tsx` component looks like this:

```
const App: React.FC = () => (
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        ...
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
);
```

I want to add my `<Nav/>` to line 4 right below `<IonReactRouter>` like I'd normally do in a standard create-react-app project.

But if I do that, the `<Nav/>` doesn't render and I get no errors.

Is that not possible? Do I need to add `<Nav/>` to every page in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got help from a friend. The problem was really silly...

The problem was just that my `<Nav/>` component needed a higher `z-index`, for some reason it got placed behind the content.